# "AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid" error in on-behalf-of scenario

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, access-token, adal

Am getting the above ADAL error when attempting to get a token for a **native** app on-behalf-of an AAD user using AcquireTokenAsync.

Scenario:
Angular single-page-app is using the adal.js library to get an access token for the user.
This token is passed to a self hosted web api which is essentially the same application (both the initial sign-in via adal.js and the self-hosted web api use the same Azure App Id).
The webapi attempts to get a new token on-behalf-of the user to call another Azure hosted web api using AcquireTokenAsync.

Code:

```
var bootstrapContext =
     ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as
          System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
var userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
var userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);
var authority = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _aadInstance, _tenant);

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new TokenCache());

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_resourceUri, _appId, userAssertion);
var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
return accessToken;
```

Note that the app registration in Azure is a native app with no app key.  If I create the app as a webapi app and use the appid and key in a ClientCredential object, the token is returned as expected.

```
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_appId, _appKey);
...
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_resourceUri, clientCredential, userAssertion);
```

I cannot get this to work with a native app.  Any suggestions?  Or any ideas why I am getting the invalid token error?

**Rationale**:
The reason I need to use a native app as opposed to a webapi app registration, the client (angluar SPA app + self-hosted webapi) is deployed on site and not on a web server.  I do not want to deploy the app with an app key, since the app keys expire and re-deploying the client app with a new key when it expires is not a great option.  Using a native app which does not have a key will avoid having to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to bypass the AcquireTokenAsync call for the first API to get a new token to call the second API?  I.e. on the initial login from adal.js, the user is granted a token to call the downstream API?

Answer (score 1):

When calling the token endpoint with the on-behalf-of grant type, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) seems to suggest you need to have a confidential client as the `client_secret` parameter is documented as required. This implies you can't use that grant type with a native (public) client type.

But if you are making the call from the self-hosted web API and it is a confidential client then the `on-behalf-of` should work.

> Is it possible to bypass the AcquireTokenAsync call for the first API
>   to get a new token to call the second API? I.e. on the initial login
>   from adal.js, the user is granted a token to call the downstream API?

Yes I think you can do this via [manifest configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest). If you amend your AAD application permissions and add delegated permissions as required between your related applications (`requiredResourceAccess`). The initial token request would need to be for the resource id of the downstream web API and this resource ID would be validated as the `audience` in each resource.

Also I believe you can set the `KnownClientApplications` in the manifest of your web API to include the app ID of your Angular app registration so once the user consents to your native app consent will be automatically created for the web API without having to consent to each API explicitly.

It really doesn't feel like a good solution though!

Also, as you question says the error you are getting relates to the JWT token format being invalid, is the raw access token definitely being passed through as `BootstrapContext`?

In the owin middleware, I seem to remember that access tokens are not carried through to the claims principal by default and you have to set

```
SaveSignInToken = true
```

as part of the `TokenValidationParameters` in the middleware.

e.g.

```
 app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],


TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{ SaveSigninToken = true, ValidAudience= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"] }
                });
```

Code example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs).

Comment: Certainly am saving the token and passing it on to the AcquireTokenAsync call.  In fact comparing this token against the non-native app token, they are identical besides the app id.  I'll try modifying the app manifest like you suggested and report back.

Comment: Adding the Angular (native) appId to the list of "knownClientApplications" in the manifest of the downstream API, doesn't appear to resolve it.  I still only see the native appId in the "aud" of the JWT token.  Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like one token relates to one `resourceid` (audience) so using the same token only works if the two web APIs check for the same `audience` in the bearer token. The original token request would need to be for the `resourceid` of the 2nd web API in the chain - the SPA and other web API should allow this `audience` as it is a `requiredResourceAccess` for them. This seems horrible though!  I think your idea of `on-behalf-of` flow is better and should work.

Comment: I'm assuming your SPA app is using the `implicit` flow - this documentation may help:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof  good luck!

Comment: I need to confirm that what I am doing is valid and possible first, and if so, then agree that I would prefer to get to the bottom of the "invalid token" error.  And yes, SPA app is using implicit flow.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get this to work if I remove the client application id altogether, but I'm not sure that is the correct solution. So, if the initial token retrieved by adal.js is for the downstream API, and the self-hosted web api audience is also the downstream API app Id, and it just passes the JWT token directly to the downstream API, and does not get a new token. This works, and achieves the desired result of not storing any app keys on the client, but it doesn't feel right, it feels like spoofing.

Answer (score 1):

**Generic Solution to Google Searches that find this.**

You may need **ClientCredential** class instead of **ClientAssertion** class in your query - or the other way around to get the right overload of AcquireToken

The real answers to this question (that are very helpful and thoughtful) help you figure this out.